# How can I multiply specific rows and column values by a constant to create a new column?

Tags: r, dataframe, multidimensional-array

I have a data frame that looks like iris for example. I want to create another column called  C1 which is a multiplication of all setosa Sepal.Length by 2.5,  all Versicolor Sepal.Length by 3.5 and all Virginica Sepal.Length by 4.5. Could someone help me with the coding, please?

Expected out

Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species       C1
           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa      5.1*2.5
           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa       4.9*2.5
           ''          ''           ''          ''       ''          ''

```
       6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5    versicolor    6.4*3.5
       6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5    versicolor    6.9*3.5
        ''          ''           ''          ''        ''          ''

       7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1     virginica     7.1*4.5
       6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8     virginica     6.3*4.5
        ''          ''           ''          ''        ''            ''
```

Comment: if any of the below worked, can you mark an answer as correct for future reference pls?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative uses the merge/join methodology to determine which of 2.5, 3.5, 4.5 to use as the multiplier.

```r
iris2 <- merge(iris,
               data.frame(Species=c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), mult=c(2.5,3.5,4.5)),
               by = "Species")
head(iris2)
#   Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width mult
# 1  setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  2.5
# 2  setosa          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  2.5
# 3  setosa          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  2.5
# 4  setosa          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  2.5
# 5  setosa          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  2.5
# 6  setosa          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  2.5
```

From this, it's trivial to calculate:

```r
head(iris2$mult * iris2$Sepal.Length, n = 10)
#  [1] 12.75 12.25 11.75 11.50 12.50 13.50 11.50 12.50 11.00 12.25
```

and store that in a column or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to create a named `vector` to replace the values based on the 'Species' and multiply with 'Sepal.Length'

```
library(dplyr)
iris <- iris %>% 
          mutate(C1 = Sepal.Length * set_names(c(2.5, 3.5, 4.5),
             c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"))[as.character(Species)])
head(iris, 3)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    C1
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 12.75
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 12.25
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 11.75
```